# Compute Bias in ''real data''

Tags: python, mean, error, bias

I would like to compute the bias of the estimate given that $X_i$ are iid $Bern(0.5)$, so $\theta = 0.5$

As an estimator I use sample mean $\hat\theta = \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i/n$

Here is the simulated distribution.

```
numSim = 1000


Trial = np.random.choice(('Head','Trial'),numSim)
Theta_hat = np.count_nonzero((Trial.column(0) == 'Head'))/numSim
Theta_hat
# In this single case Theta_hat = 0.492
```

Now to compute bias I must compute the expected value of sample mean.
Must I use this value and do $E[\hat\theta]-\theta = 0.492-0.5$

or should I compute $\hat\theta$ over many trials to get yet another estimate for the expected value and use it during the computation?

```
 estimate = make_array()
 for i in np.arange(100):
    Trial = np.random.choice(('Head','Trial'),numSim)
    Theta_hat = np.count_nonzero((Trial.column(0) == 'Head'))/numSim
    estimate = np.append(estimate,Theta_hat)
```

Than compute mean of estimate?

Comment: Are you perhaps confusing "error" with "bias"?  Bias doesn't refer to any specific realization of the estimator but rather to the expected value of the estimator.  $E[\hat{\theta}]$ is a meaningless expression when you have a calculated value for $\hat{\theta}$ that you are using; it's not an expected value at that point, it's an observed value.

Comment: @jbowman Yes, you are right it is an observed value minus the true parameter and in theory in this case it is equal to 0. I would like to compute the quadratic risk of $\hat\theta$ in practice if it is possible. By the same logic, $Var(\hat\theta)$ is also 0, than it is impossible to compute it in practice, isn't it?

Comment: But I think people compute it in some way

Comment: People usually use math to solve for these expressions.  For example, we know $Var(X_i) = p(1-p)$, so $Var(\Sigma X_i) = np(1-p)$, and $Var(\Sigma X_i/n) = p(1-p)/n$, and there's your $Var(\hat{\theta})$.